# Why does my furnace shut off with the fan running?

Tags: electrical, furnace

I changed out the thermocouple and I’m still having the same problem with it starting and running for a while then will shut off and the blower motor will just run. I took off the high limit switch, and took a few pictures of it, I don’t know if I’ll be able to change the settings on a high limit switch for it to allow the furnace to get a little bit hotter or not. I don’t even know if the high limit switch is the problem. I had the furnace running for a while since my last post. I cleaned off the thermal coupling and it seemed to work. the area I keep my furnace in got really really hot one day and then it hasn’t worked since.

Update: I also noticed that exhaust duct work got kicked out of the “hole” it was in. There must’ve been a hole that got covered with bricks. Please let me know if this is something that would be causing this problem. [image: hole that furnace and hot water heater were vented through, elbow was just sitting in the hole]

[image]

[image: high limit switch]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, if you're going to mention an old post, _link to it_.

Comment: Mention of the area getting really hot, sounds like a control did not work to shut off the heating.  This could have caused other problems also due to the high heat.  Would be best to have the furnace checked out by a repair person.  High heat can crack the burn chamber and/or damaged other controls, making the furnace dangerous to use.

Comment: Is there any fixing a cracked burner chamber? How would I go about narrowing it down to that ? @crip659

Comment: In most places the only fix allowed is replacement, but need to have the chamber inspected first, this is probably beyond what a DIYer can do.  Quite possible the only damage was done to the controls/sensors and which one caused the over heat in the first place.

Comment: I have no idea what your "exhaust duct/hole" picture is supposed to be showing us - it seems to be too much of a close up pic to be of much use. In any case, please ask that as a separate question. [The rules here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) require one question per post to keep things moving smoothly.